# Micro cloud foundry - VCAP ROUTER: 404 - DESTINATION NOT FOUND?

Tags: ruby, linux, ssh, cloud-foundry, vmc

I had micro cloud foundry vmware running in network bridge mode. Installed with token generated from the micro cloud foundry site. I had deployed two applications, one from spring suite and other using vmc command line from windows. Both apps where available through url from outside. I had changed the memory limit from STS and updated the application, after that the both apps are showing vcap error while accessing from the browser.

I had found that there is a network.rb file editing to resolve this, but I dont know how to do this from the micro cloud foundry console ?

The url found the above tip is http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/21042938-mcf-1-2-0-configuration-error-s

But my micro cloud foundry url http://api.demo22.cloudfoundry.me/ is still showing up with no errors.

Please help to resolve this.. thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem with memory selection for apps. The 512MB (Default) must be given for each app. choosing a memeory below that gives  error in application. I had choosed 64MB from STS (spring tool suite) for application which I pushed to mcf, and it fails to start the apps. I removed the apps and re deploy it with default 512 MB and its work.

Thanks for all the leads...

Answer (score 1):

If you review that forum post closely you will see a section which describes how to obtain the command line for editing the network.rb file. Try this link:

http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/21042938-mcf-1-2-0-configuration-error-s#post_21058483

Comment: since I dont have any idea in linux command I am utterly failed in editing that file. I used vi network.rb for this but it created a netwoeb.rb.swap file and ended in mishap. I will try again and let you know the result @eightyoctane ... thank you very much.